# Help with graphing "continuity from left or right"

Tags: limits, continuity, graphing-functions

[Problem (#2 specifically)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw7z1.jpg)

Honestly the part I specifically have a problem with is the "f is discontinuous from the right at -5" and the other f is continuous. I sorta get the definitions of being continuous from the left and right but I'm having trouble putting it into the graph.

[Here's how far I've gotten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ncUa.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.
Plus, add the photos to the question directly, be careful for your photos to be clear and clean!

Comment: @Nizar Thanks for the tips, sorry I'll definitely keep those in mind for my future posts and comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph could be a bit more precise but I think your intentions are good.

You've got the limits correct so far, although it's safe to add a bit of a dashed or dotted line connecting the $1$ (on the $y$-axis) to the the "hole" to indicate it's at height $1$ (because it seems to have a lower value now). You could do the same with the dot on $(2,5)$.

The function with your graph is indeed continuous from the right at $-1$, but notice that $f(-1)$ doesn't have to be $1$. The graph has to approach $1$ *from the left* though (due to the given limit), but $f(-1)$ can have any other value as long as the function is continuous from the right.

For the part at $x=-5$, the function doesn't exist on the left of it (due to the domain beginning at $x=-5$), but the graph has to be discontinuous (from the right) at this point: so approach a certain value for $x \to -5$ but give $f(-5)$ another value than this limiting value (like at $x = 2$).